# Outlook defaults to sending emails at 5:00

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

This has changed overnight, and as far as I know was not caused by a user preference change. When composing (or repling to) a message, under "Delivery Options", a delay before sending is always set: "Do not deliver before: 8/13/2013 5:00PM"

Unchecking this box does nothing - if I close the dialog and reopen it, the value has returned. How can I change the default value here to send messages automatically?

There are no rules specified on outgoing messages.

Clarification: This is Outlook 2010 running Exchange 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dude! You broke my Outlook! I hadn't noticed anything wrong with it, *until I read your post* and was able to reproduce the exact behavior you described!

OK, so at first I was baffled. And then it occurred to me that the problem is due to *operator error*, triggered by *poor UX design.* (At least, that was my problem, and I assume you're in the same boat.)

The setting that I believe you are referring to is on the "Options" ribbon, in the "More Options" section: the button labeled `Delay Delivery`. Pressing this button opens a dialog that allows you to set the delay-delivery settings. What was *not* immediately obvious to me is that pressing this button ALSO *automatically enables the delay* (with a 5pm default time, as you said). If you close the dialog box at this point the fact that the email is now in the "delay mode" is indicated by the fact that the `Delay Delivery` button is now glowing gold. (The idea is that you can press the Delay button, then immediately press Close, thereby toggling the delay mode ON.)

To *disable* the delay mode, simply click that button again and uncheck the "Do not deliver before" box, then close the dialog. Notice that the `Delay Delivery` button is *no longer glowing gold.* Your email will be delivered immediately.

The mistake that we both made was that we tried to confirm that the delay mode was disabled by opening the dialog box and expecting to see the checkbox still unchecked. But the act of opening the dialog *automatically sets that checkbox* (as I explained above). So it *looks* like the value was never unset when in fact it was.

---

This is poor UX design, in my opinion, because it does not conform to the form & behavior of other similar ribbon buttons in MS Office. This button is acting like a "partial" toggle button. It should have instead been designed like the "Crop" button that is used in the "Picture Tools" Format ribbon: The top half of the button should be a toggle (press on/ press off), and the bottom half should  open the settings dialog (with an inverted triangle on the button, as an indicator). Such functionality would be less prone to the confusion that stymied us.

Oh, and by the way, welcome to superuser!

Comment: Turns out something else was keeping emails in the Outbox, and I was in fact creating this problem as a side effect. Thanks!